# Mysterious object

Tags: riddle, word

Cut me, I am still normal.

Change my colour, I am still normal.

The only way you can make me change is to draw on me.

Change one of the letters and I am a dog.

Change another one and I am poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Paper

**Cut me, I am still normal.**

> cut a piece of paper and you just have two pieces of *paper*

**Change my colour, I am still normal.**

> Colored paper is still *paper*

**The only way you can make me change is to draw on me.**
I don't really have an answer for this, but just a thought

> If you draw on a piece of paper - it's no longer just paper - it can be considered a piece of work/art

**Change one of the letters and I am a dog.**

> Piper - the aiport K9 dog? [link](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/animalia/wp/2018/01/05/rip-piper-a-heroic-dog-who-kept-airport-runways-safe/)

**Change another one and I am poor.**

> Pa**u**per - this is technically adding a letter, so may not be it

Comment: That was correct! @WELZ, I wish I could give you an award.

Comment: @EthanSmurf you can upvote.and accept the answer by clicking on the green tick.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> DOT?

*Cut me, I am still normal.*
*Change my colour, I am still normal.*
*The only way you can make me change is to draw on me.*

> Mathematically, a dot is a point with zero dimensions, zero distance in any direction. So you can cut it, but half of zero is still zero, it's the same thing. You can change its colour, but that only needs a zero amount of ink, so it's still the same thing. If you draw on it, though, then you can extend it to a line or a curve, which will be something different.

*Change one of the letters and I am a dog.*

> DOG is one letter different from DOT.

*Change another one and I am poor.*

> SOT is one letter different from DOT. A sot might be poor, having wasted all his money on alcohol?